# Insert rows with unique numeric ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table dbo.Register with unique ID column. I need to insert many rows into this table with, but any with unique identifier, like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Register (ID, Name, State, Comment)
Select
NEWID(),
Name,
State,
Comment
From dbo.OtherTable
```

But NEWID() returns long string of characters: *2D0D098E-2FFE-428A-B4EF-950C89FFF83A*, but i need unique integer ID. e.g next free ID in this table.

Edit.
I can't modify this table. I only need to insert rows into current structure.

Sample Records:

```
+--------+------------+--------------+------------+
|   ID   |    Name    |    State     |  Comment   |
+--------+------------+--------------+------------+
| 153299 | Zapytania  | Przyjeto     | NieDotyczy |
| 153300 | Zapytania  | Przyjeto     | NieDotyczy |
| 153301 | Zapytania  | Przyjeto     | NieDotyczy |
| 153302 | Zapytania  | Przyjeto     | NieDotyczy |
| 153303 | Zapytania  | Przyjeto     | NieDotyczy |
| 153304 | Dyspozycje | Zakonczono   | NieDotyczy |
| 153305 | Zapytania  | DoRealizacji | NULL       |
| 153306 | Zapytania  | Przyjeto     | NieDotyczy |
| 153307 | Zapytania  | Przyjeto     | NieDotyczy |
| 153308 | Dyspozycje | Przyjeto     | NieDotyczy |
+--------+------------+--------------+------------+
```

Definition of ID column already is:

```
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Create ID column to be INT Identitity(1,1) ... that way it will be self increased and you won't have to worry about it nor insert it

Comment: UniqueId column value with int is not good if u are using that id for passing parameter though web application , ex : as a query string. Better you should use GUID like you have implemented NEWID().

Comment: So, what you want is the values and properties of an identity column without declaring the `ID` column as an identity column?

Comment: Which version of Sql Server are you using?

Comment: If already your column definition contain `IDENTITY(1,1)` no need of insertion. Actually you can't insert too.

Comment: @ShakeerMirza, unless you `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Register] OFF`

Comment: @Jodrell Yes I agree. I have suggested him to know about `IDENTITY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't make `ID` an `IDENTITY` column which would be a much better idea, you could instead use a `SEQUENCE`.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[RegisterId]  
    START WITH 153309  
    INCREMENT BY 1;  
GO
```

and then,

```
INSERT [dbo].[Register]
    (
        [ID],
        [Name],
        [State],
        [Comment]
    )
SELECT
        NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[RegisterId] [ID],
        [Name],
        [State],
        [Comment]
    FROM
        [dbo].[OtherTable];
```

---

alternatively, if you can't change the schema you could use a temporary table to make use of an `IDENTITY` column,

```
DECLARE @maxId INT = SELECT MAX([ID]) + 1 FROM [dbo].[Register];

DECLARE @createTemp NVARCHAR(4000) = N'
CREATE TABLE #TempRegister
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(' + CAST(@maxId, NVARCHAR(14)) + ', 1),
    [Name] NVARCHAR(?),
    [State] NVARCHAR(?),
    [Comment] NVARCHAR(?)
);';

EXEC sp_executesql @createTemp;
GO

INSERT #TempRegister
    (
        [Name],
        [State],
        [Comment]
    )
SELECT
        [Name],
        [State],
        [Comment]
    FROM
        [dbo].[OtherTable];

INSERT [dbo].[Register]
SELECT
        [ID],
        [Name],
        [State],
        [Comment]
    FROM
        #TempRegister;

DROP TABLE #TempRegister;
```

Comment: second method is good, but i have problem with syntax:
First I have problem:
The definition for column 'ID_Sprawy' must include a data type.

If i add datatype like: [ID] [int] IDENTITY(@maxId, 1),

I get a next problem:
Incorrect syntax near '@maxId'.

Comment: @Gruby amended answer

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by doing like below

```
DECLARE @ID INT;
SELECT @ID=ISNULL(MAX(ID),0) FROM dbo.Register
--Isnull to handle first record for the table

INSERT INTO dbo.Register (ID, Name, State, Comment)
Select
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT 1))+ @ID,
Name,
State,
Comment
From dbo.OtherTable
```

Per the edit there is no need of specifying the column in Insert list. You can skip the column and do INSERT & SELECT.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Register ( Name, State, Comment)
Select 
    Name,
    State,
    Comment
    From dbo.OtherTable
```

Better you need to look at [IDENTITY (Property) (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)

Comment: Add ISNULL(@ID, 0) ... maybe Register table is empty

Comment: or use subquery instead of variable

Comment: Sub query will hit every time. Better if it is satatic @TedoG.

Comment: @ShakeerMirza unless you have to worry about concurrency but, if you have to worry about concurrency and performance this approach is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Concurrency might be an issue. But I think no performance hit. And OP wants to do it in bulk `insert many rows into this `. So I thought there is no concurrency issue. @Jodrell

Comment: If there are many rows in `Register` and/or `OtherTable` this approach will use more resources than an `IDENTITY` column or a `SEQUENCE` and without a `TRANSACTION` it is susceptible to concurrency issues. However, as you say, for a single user, there is an advantage to precalculating the row number offset and this approach will work without additional schema changes to the database.

Comment: @Jodrell Yes. If we talk about Identity, there is no better way than Identity. As OP said he has no chance to change the schema I attempted it with Row_Number. And the thing is he already had Identity property on it :(

Answer (score 2):

Run next script ....

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Register
DROP column ID

ALTER TABLE dbo.Register
add ID int identitity (1, 1)    

INSERT INTO dbo.Register (Name, State, Comment)
Select
 Name,
 State,
 Comment
From dbo.OtherTable
```

EDIT:

With new info, just do

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Register (Name, State, Comment)
Select
    Name,
    State,
    Comment
From dbo.OtherTable
```

ID Column will take care of itself ...

Comment: I can't modify this table. I only need to insert rows into.

Comment: Check definition of ID column ... and let us know is it identitiy already and show us some data from that table ... do 'select top 10 * from dbo.Register'

Comment: @Gruby then you need to make that clear in the question.